# Clone entity and all related entities in CakePHP 3

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

In my CakePHP 3 app, I have a somewhat elaborate tree of entities that I need to clone and save.

The root of the structure is a Questionnaire, a Questionnaire hasMany Questions, each Question hasMany Fields, etc. (it goes deeper). Now I want the user to be able to define a new questionnaire by copying an old one. Then they can change whatever they need.

I can get a dump of what I need to copy by using `$questionnaire->$this->Questionnaires->get($id)` with the appropriate *contain* fields. Is there a clever way to save this as a bunch of new entities while preserving the data and the structure between them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the best possible way would be following work flow:

1. Get object you want to clone
2. Go through the collection and remove all ID's
3. Convert to array and use that in `$this->Questionnaires->newEntity($arrayData, ['associated' => ['Questions', '...']]);`
4. Now save the new entity with all the related data you want to keep

AFAIK there's no "smarter" way of cloning an entity with associations in Cake 3 :-)

Comment: what is the point of converting to an array and back to an entity here? Assuming that the object to be cloned is already an entity, will the result of this double-conversion be different in any useful way?

Comment: Because you need it as array data in the `newEntity()` (http://api.cakephp.org/3.1/class-Cake.ORM.Table.html#_newEntity)

It's worth a try to clone the entity, remove the ID's and then try to use it in a  `save()` - I'm not sure if that will save it as a new entity, but it actually could do that..  (http://api.cakephp.org/3.1/class-Cake.ORM.Table.html#_save)

Comment: Yes, I think that if you remove all the IDs and call `isNew(true)`, you'll get the same result as converting to an array and back. In the midst of building a function that will do this recursively and generically (based on the associations of the model), but it hasn't been fully tested yet.

Comment: Aha! I'm not even sure that anything besides removing the ID is necessary then...

Answer (score 6):

You could also use [this plugin](https://github.com/riesenia/cakephp-duplicatable). You only have to configure the behavior and it gives you other functionalities, like setting default values or appending text to some field.

Answer (score 1):

use EntityInteface toArray() to get all its fields:

```
$newEtity = $someTable->newEntity($oldEtity->toArray());
unset($newDevice->created);
unset($newDevice->id);
$someTable->save($newEntity);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$original = $this->Table->get($id)->toArray();
$copy = $this->Table->newEntity();
$copy = $this->Table->patchEntity($copy, $original);

unset($copy['id']);
// Unset or modify all others what you need

$this->Table->save($copy);
```

Work perfectly like this :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the way I did it when I needed something similar (adapted to the Questionnaire example):

```
// load the models
$this->loadModel('Questionnaire');
$this->loadModel('Questions');
// get the questions to questionnaire association - will need the PK name
$qAssoc = $this->{'Questions'}->associations()->get('Questionnaire');
// get the existing entity to copy
$existingEntity = $this->{'Questionnaire'}->get($id, [
    'contain' => ['Questions'],
]);
// clean up the existing entity
$existingEntity->unsetProperty($this->{'Questionnaire'}->getPrimaryKey());
$existingEntity->unsetProperty('created');
$existingEntity->unsetProperty('modified');
// clean up the associated records of the existing entity
foreach ($existingEntity->questions as &$q) {
    $q->unsetProperty($this->{'Questions'}->getPrimaryKey());
    $q->unsetProperty($qAssoc->getForeignKey());
}
// create a new entity and patch it with source data
$newEntity = $this->{'Questionnaire'}->patchEntity(
        $this->{'Questionnaire'}->newEntity(),
        $existingEntity->toArray()
);
// save the new entity
$result = $this->{'Questionnaire'}->save($existingEntity);
```

References:

- https://api.cakephp.org/3.0/class-Cake.ORM.Entity.html
- https://api.cakephp.org/3.0/class-Cake.ORM.Table.html